# Counting and filtering products/entities in faceted type (EAV) filter

Tags: php, mysql, entity-attribute-value

I'm building faceted filter for online shop based on EAV (ENTITY - MODEL -VALUE called PRODUCT - OPTION -VALUE in this topic)  model.
Filtering products using following logic:

```
  ... pv.value_id IN (option_value1 or option_value1) AND pv.value_id IN (option_value2 or option_value2)
```

In query realized like this (without FIND_IN_SET but provide many queries):

> $pids=array();
>   foreach ($option as $values) {
>   $sqli = "SELECT product_id FROM product_to_value WHERE value_id in ('" . implode(",", $values) . "') ";
>   $query =$db->query($sqli);
>
> foreach ($query->rows as $row){
>             $pids[] = $row['product_id'];
>        }  }
>
> $sql .= " AND p.product_id IN (" . implode(",", $pids) . ")";

Another task is a solution for counting products for ​​option values considering dependence (eg query below selects all the possible products given the existing filtering, 10 - is a value of option1 and 6,8 -is a values of option2)

> SELECT p.product_id, pv.value_id, GROUP_CONCAT(pv.value_id) as
>   value_ids FROM `product` p INNER JOIN product_to_value pv ON
>   (p.product_id = pv.product_id) WHERE pv.value_id<>0 GROUP BY
>   product_id HAVING ( FIND_IN_SET( 10, value_ids ) >0 ) AND (
>   FIND_IN_SET( 6, value_ids ) >0 OR FIND_IN_SET( 8, value_ids ) >0 )

And after that, get values count for selected products.

**Question:** This looks like not perfect solution, any ideas how to improve this code for counting/filtering products considering filter option. Use or note FIND_IN_SET

And SQL schema for better understanding:

```
  CREATE TABLE `option` (
    `option_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `status` int(1) default '0',
    `sort_order` int(10) default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`option_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  CREATE TABLE `option_value` (
    `value_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
    `option_id` int(10) default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`value_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


  CREATE TABLE `product_to_value` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`product_id`,`value_id`,`option_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  CREATE TABLE `product` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`product_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**UPDATE:**

Aditional variant without FIND_IN_SET.

> SELECT product_id FROM product_to_value WHERE  product_id IN  (SELECT
>   product_id FROM product_to_value WHERE value_id IN (6,8) GROUP BY
>   product_id) AND product_id IN  (SELECT product_id FROM
>   product_to_value WHERE value_id IN (10) GROUP BY product_id ) GROUP BY
>   product_id

Which variant is better or different solution?

Comment: Consider providing an sqlfiddle of same TOGETHER WITH the desired result.

Comment: simple example, think will enough for understanding http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72872/6